# Web Scraping with an Incrementing ID and Login

Tags: python, html, web

I’m trying to create a web scraper in python for a website called Canvas LMS to find a course link. The course link is formatted like this: [schoolname].instructure.com/courses/[id] I need to figure out how to have a bot log in with my api key and check all IDs from 1 to 10,000 for courses that does not contain the phrase “Unauthorized” or “Page Not Found” in the title so I can check them manually. However, I cannot figure out how to do any of this, as there is no guide (to my knowledge) that says how to do any of this. Tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a similar problem a few weeks back and found a solution.

Firstly, there is extensive Canvas LMS documentation available [here](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.graphql.html)

Secondly, find the relevant tags which can be identified and then copied to a download set. I forked a repository [here](https://github.com/john-hix/scrape-canvas) and ran as a Docker container on my local machine.

I would also recommend viewing the data in a Jupyter Notebook. As a starter (and I do not advocate nested 'for loops' but you get the idea) try these:

```
from canvasapi import Canvas
canvas = Canvas("your-course-url", "api-token")

#Get courses and print
courses = canvas.get_courses()
for course in courses:
    print(f"{course}")

#Get modules and print
modules = course.get_modules()
for module in modules:
    print(f"{module}")

#Get modules items and print
module_items = course.get_module_items()
for item in module_items:
    print(f"{item}")
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To get started you need to generate your API token which you can do by following Canvas LMS's short [guide](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Student-Guide/How-do-I-manage-API-access-tokens-as-a-student/ta-p/273):

In summary, click on the **Settings** option under the **Accounts** tab on the sidebar. Scroll down on the settings page to the **Approved Integrations** where you'll be able to create a new token.

Then you can use the canvasapi library with your course link **([schoolname].instructure.com)** & API token to start scraping away.

They also have a very helpful [community](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Canvas-Developers-Group/gh-p/developers) for more niche problems

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34418755)